# Blender 2.83: is it a bug that Viewport Shading Gets Laggy after Plugging Layer Weight, Fresnel, and Noise Combo into Bump/Normal?

Tags: 3d-view

I made a node set up combining layer weight, fresnel, and noise (a little more complex than that). Anyways, when I hooked it into bump, then into normal, it basically broke Viewport Shading preview (super laggy impossible to do anything with). Everything else worked fine: Wireframe, Solid, even Cycles preview. I was in 2.83 and since I was really confused when it first happened, I opened it in 2.82 and it continued to do the same thing.

Is this a bug? Can you reproduce it on your end? Can someone give me details as to why it acts like it does?

[image]
[image: the end of bright/contleads into color 1 of multiply then to a bump node then to normal]

Comment: I wrote the above before I went to bed if you need a better understanding here is a video I made earlier. 2.83 and 2.82 compliant. 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tHI2wjI6wyo&feature=youtu.be

Comment: It seems like adding noise to it and using it, in general, does it. It was going well for a bit but after hooking it into spec enough it started lagging as well. Just so happens plugging in bump gives you that result immediately. Plugging it into spec takes a few before it decides to lag.
Without noise it seems to run fine. Not sure if it is due to 4D or not. I switched some to 2D and it seems to not have improved. Will continue prodding.

Comment: I had an edit button but it is gone. I would combine these together but can't. For Spec 3D fixes it. 4D is at fault for that. 3D and bump do not work but if you bring it down to 2D it works at least with one. So it seems the algorithm for 3D, 4D and potential 2D if stacked enough will lead to this. Still interested as to why. Hopefully this will help you guys. Sorry for the extra comments stacking up but I dunno what happened to edit.